# SSMS: Create a View

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I am trying to create a view, but I keep getting errors.

Can anyone help me with this error?

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Code:

```
CREATE VIEW RecentAlbums 
AS
    SELECT
        Artists.ArtistName, Albums.AlbumName, Albums.ReleaseDate, Genre.Genre
    FROM 
        Albums
    INNER JOIN 
        Artists ON Albums.ArtistId = Artists.ArtistId
    INNER JOIN 
        Genre ON Albums.GenreId = Genre.GenreId
    WHERE 
        (Artists.ArtistName > DATEADD(year, - 10, GETDATE()));

SELECT * FROM RecentAlbums;
```

Regards

Comment: Is your Artists.ArtistName column is datetime field type ?

Comment: Did you intend to use this: `Albums.ReleaseDate > DATEADD(year, - 10, GETDATE())` ?

Comment: Are you seriously comparing ArtistName which might be narchar to datetime? Or the DataType of ArtistName is datetime?

Answer (score 0):

because dateadd returns datetime and you try to use in where different type columns.

you can see below article about Dateadd to understand how it works.
http://www.codefolders.com/articles/sql/date-and-time-functions/dateadd().html